# YouTube (yt) Ruby gem not working

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, rubygems

After following the [installation instructions](https://fullscreen.github.io/yt/index.html) and executing `$ yt info`, I am presented with the following error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/yt-0.25.39/lib/yt/request.rb:83:in `run': A request to YouTube API caused an unexpected server error: (Yt::Errors::ServerError)
{}

You can retry the same request manually by running:
curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" "https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?video_id=BPNYv0vd78A"
```

I am also unable to make simple requests using a server API key, as described [here](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt/#apps-that-do-not-require-user-interactions).

Is anybody else having issues with this Ruby gem?

Comment: If you follow the instruction that you provide, you can see there that you need to add this line gem 'yt', '~> 0.25.6, However, the error that you get is /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/yt-0.25.39/lib/yt/request, maybe the version that you use makes the error. Also try to follow the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/youtube/v3) of YouTube for ruby client. And this is the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have gem 'yt', '~> 0.25.6 in my Gemfile but it chooses to install v0.25.39, for some reason. I'll give the official YouTube Ruby API a try instead.

Comment: I think that's because the video id in the `bin/yt` file is not available any more. I would try `yt info <video id>` of an available video (with any annotation)